# Flash AS2 play/stop movieclip on Button click

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

So i have a button. On click it does this

```
on (release) {
gotoAndstop (91)}
```

on frame 91 i have a movieclip.

And inside the movieclip i've used `stop();` to stop the animation from repeating.
But when i click on the button again. It wont animate. Its stopped permanently.

I want to be able to keep clicking on the button so it runs the animation only once.

What do i do?

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour. The movieclip is at frame 91 and stays there when you use gotoAndStop(91), nothing changes, so nothing restarts and no frame scripts will be executed.

If you want to control the inner movieclip, you need to give it an instance name and then use instanceName.play() or instanceName.gotoAndPlay() on it to restart the animation. Make sure the instance is already available when you try to control it.